# How can I attach my wireless printer with a WPS button to my router (Google Home Nest) which does not have a WPS button?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer

I have an older wireless printer (Samsung M2020w) that I cannot attach to my new Google Nest Router, which  does not have a WPS button (which my old router did). Is there a way or workaround to attach my printer to a router that does not have a WPS button, avoid having to buy a new printer which is compatible with Nest? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should be mentioned in the Installation manual that came with the printer.

Connect the printer using USB to a Windows or Mac computer.

You can now configure the Wifi settings manually using the Samsung Easy Wireless Setup program that came with the printer on the driver-CD or that you can download from the Samsung website.
The software saves the settings to the printer. After this you can disconnect the USB cable and use the printer via Wifi without having to use WPS.

Comment: These instructions worked. Two follow-on questions: Do I have to repeat this procedure if I want to print on another computer in my home? And, how do I print from my mobile phone (Samsung S8+) ?

Comment: 1) No, you just install the printer on the second computer as a "network printer". You can use the samsung driver software for this.
2) Samsung has the Samsung Mobile Print app that you can install on an adroid phone.

Comment: Will Samsung Easy Wireless Setup also work with a Microsoft Surface Pro 7? ty

Comment: @AndyTsitouris Why wouldn't it? A Surface Pro is still a regular Intel CPU based computer that runs WIndows.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it does not appear to be the OP's problem, I'd like to suggest others (possibly arriving here like me  after struggling for ages to connect their HP printer to a Google Nest Wi-Fi Router) try and disable WPA3 in the Google Home App Wi-Fi settings.

[Apparently](https://support.google.com/googlenest/thread/70977697?hl=en&msgid=71972828), Nest Wifi tries to accommodate WPA2 devices even when set to WPA3 mode, but some devices, most commonly HP printers judging by other forums, aren't able to handle a WPA3 network even in backwards compatibility mode.

Took quite a bit of trial and error to stumble upon this solution, but once you know exactly what you need to google, [you do find others who encountered exactly the same issue and solved it the same way](https://support.google.com/googlenest/thread/70977697).

[image: Google Home app screenshot]